# Fetch Google Places Data using Python

Tags: google-api, python-requests

I'm trying to write a short python script which fetches data from Google Places API and exports it as a .csv file.

Unfortunately I'm stuck right at the beginning.

I want to use requests package but my machine cannot find it.

I've installed Python 3.5 on my Mac and when I use pip to install requests it says:

> Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages

But when I run the program I get an import error which says:

> ImportError: No module named requests

Do you have any ideas how i can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Much love.

Answer (score 1):

Use `python -m pip install requests` instead. Your pip installation was probably for a different version.